# When publishing through Amazon, can you get some free codes for specific people?

Tags: self-publishing, amazon

I'm hoping to publish a book in July or August through Amazon, probably with a paperback option as well as E-book. There's been some people who've really helped along the way, and with another huge wave of reviewing before I publish, there's gonna be a lot of people who help. I know that Betas mostly work for free, but I want to give back just a bit by letting them have a copy of the book, preferably for free.

So, is there a way to get a dozen or so 'free codes' to give to the people who've helped the most when publishing through Amazon? Reduced price works as well but free is better. I'd like the codes to be for the paperback version rather than ebook because you can normally get those for free with Kindle Unlimited.

Comment: You could just get free copies for yourself, and then mail them/give them to the people who you want to give them to. (I have no idea if the author can get free copies themselves (although I would think that they would) but if you can't figure out how to obtain the codes/if they exist, this is an alternative method you can look into.)

Comment: I would agree with Joe Kerr here. If there is no such code, simply request a few extra free copies to give to your beta readers.

Comment: Talk to the publisher or your literary agent. They should set you up, or tell you if they won't.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not ask Amazon directly?

Answer (score 1):

I've published 45 books on Amazon and have been paid well for every one. I wouldn't hesitate to spend part of Amazon's money (paid to me) to buy what copies I want. I've never asked for a free anything.

Comment: Amazon also has the option to buy "author copies" at printing cost (+ shipping) https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G202132360

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google search on KDP free and got the following:

> To set up a free book promotion, follow these steps:
> In your Bookshelf, click on the ellipsis button (“…”) under the Book Actions menu next to any book enrolled in KDP Select.
> Select “KDP Select Info”.
> Under “Run a Price Promotion”, select “Free Book Promotion”. ...
> Click “Create a new Free Book Promotion”.

If these steps don't work or there are more steps needed, do a search on "How to get my KDP book for free." I can't test this out right now.

Comment: The free book promo makes the book free for everyone.